# How to declare new variable names in Angular 17 templates?

Tags: angular, angular17

In all Angular versions < 17 it was possible to declare new variable names, or better: create variable aliases in the templates, like this simplfied example:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="objectlist$ | async as list">
    {{ list.name }}
</ng-container>
```

Now Angular 17 has introduced the new `@if` syntax (what I really like). So I would convert the snippet like this:

```
@if (objectlist$ | async as list) {
    {{ list.name }}
}
```

However this is not working because `as list` doesn't work with the new syntax scheme. But how can I achieve the logic from my initial script same with the new syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Alias is still supported on `@if` in the [control flow syntax](https://blog.angular.io/meet-angulars-new-control-flow-a02c6eee7843) if you add a semi colon (;) after the `async` pipe:

```
@if (objectlist$ | async; as list) {
    {{ list.name }}
}
```

However, alias is not supported on `@if` with `@else` in the control flow syntax. `@if` is supported just for backwards compatibility.  See this Issue on the Angular GitHub repository: [Allow to alias the @else if blocks in control flow syntax #52103](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/52103).

The relevant parts are:

> We were discussing this some time ago, but decided not to support it,
> because the alias is there only for backwards compatibility with ngIf.

and

> We discussed this particular point extensively during the design of
> control flow, and decided against expanding support for as. In
> particular @if in signal components will not support it at all,
> because it's incompatible with signal data flow.
>
> as is effectively a local variable declaration, similar to let inner =
> outer.expression;. If you imagine the outer expression reads signals,
> then the inner expression is caching the resulting value in order to
> use it in a child template. This "loses reactivity" - the child
> template would never update because it isn't doing the signal reads
> itself. Instead, computed signals solve this problem in a much more
> canonical way.